# Opencv extract exact match of image from dataset?

Tags: c++, opencv

In my project I want to extract exact match of the image (coming through camera) from the data set.Data set contains the set of positive and negative images.Images in data set having small differences .So problem is that if i use "features detector "algorithm it gives me no of images but i want exact match .how can i do this?

Comment: If it is exact match, the difference between the two matched imaged should be zero. So you just compute all the differences and find the one with difference being 0. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i am having real part of bracket of vehicle and I captured images of that from different views and angles(side,top,bottom,front,different angles).So whenever I put that bracket in front of the camera (suppose front view in front of camera) exact (i.e front view)image should be extracted from the set of images.so how to do this?

Comment: Can you use some sample images to illustrate your problem? Not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Welding_cracks.svg I am having the same real part with me and its images from different views(images are captured by camera).